# Copy content of a directory to another Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to copy the content of a directory into another directory on a Jenkins file.
My first attempt was using xcopy, but I'm getting an error ( Invalid number of parameters).

```
bat 'xcopy cashplus-backoffice/cashplus-backoffice-ui/build/web cashplus-backoffice/src/main/resources/static /e /h'
```

My second attempt was to using File Operation plugin as follows:

```
                fileOperations([fileCopyOperation(
                   excludes: '',
                   flattenFiles: false,
                   includes: 'cashplus-backoffice/cashplus-backoffice-ui/build/web/**',
                   targetLocation: 'cashplus-backoffice/src/main/resources/static'
                )])
```

The problem with this solution is that it copy the whole tree and the content of the source folder ( cashplus-backoffice/cashplus-backoffice-ui/build/web. I want just the content of the web folder ).
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `xcopy` command and use `\\` instead of `\` for windows.
Example:

```
bat "xcopy /E /H C:\\Data\\myfiles C:\\Data\\Documents\\"
```